# Trying to Save Multiple Files in Django: didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Please help out. I'm trying to save multiple files in Django using CreateView. But I'm only able to save the last file on the list selected. Then i changed my views to a function view matching most of the explanation i saw in here .. Now i'm getting Value Error.

Below are the two views. The CreateView(CBV) and the function View. 
Thanks

CreateView

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UpdateMatterCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = UpdateMatterForm
    model = MatterUpdates
    template_name = 'matter/matter_instance_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('matter_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = UpdateMatterForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.client_id = self.kwargs['client_id']
            form.instance.firm_id = self.kwargs['firm_id']
            form.instance.matter_id = self.kwargs['matter_id']
            form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id

            files = self.request.FILES.getlist('files')

            for f in files:
                docs_path = Documents.objects.create(matter_update_id=self.kwargs['matter_id'], file_path=f)
                docs_path.save()

        return super(UpdateMatterCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateMatterCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['object'] = Matter.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['matter_id'])

        return context
```

Function Views

```
def update_matter_instance(request, firm_id, client_id, matter_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateMatterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.instance.title
            content = form.instance.content
            created_date = form.instance.created_date
            created_time = form.instance.created_time

            matter_update_link = MatterUpdates.objects.create(firm_id=firm_id, client_id=client_id,
                                                              matter_id=matter_id, title=title, content=content,
                                                              created_date=created_date, created_time=created_time,
                                                              user_id=request.user.id, )
            matter_update_link.save()

            files = request.FILES.getlist('files')

            for f in files:
                docs_path = Documents.objects.create(matter_update_id=matter_id, file_path=f)
                docs_path.save()

            return redirect('matter_list')

        else:
            form = UpdateMatterForm()

        return render(request, 'matter/matter_instance_create.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateMatterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MatterUpdates
        exclude = ['matter', 'client', 'firm', 'sys_date', 'user']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Title'}),

            'content': RichTextFormField(),

            'created_date': forms.DateInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy'}),
            'created_time': forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'timepicker2', 'type': 'text'}),

            'files': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})
        }
```

urls.py

FUCNTION REGEX

```
url(r'^legal_stallion/stallion_matter_instance_update/(?P<firm_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<client_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/'
        r'(?P<matter_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.update_matter_instance, name='update_matter_instance'),
```

CLASS REGEX

```
url(r'^legal_stallion/stallion_matter_instance_update/(?P<firm_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/(?P<client_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/'
        r'(?P<matter_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$', views.UpdateMatterCreateView.as_view(), name='update_matter_instance'),
```

Templates

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal " id="commentForm" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{ form.errors }}
                                            <div class="form-group "  style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px">
                                                <label for="cname" class="control-label col-lg-3">Title <span style="color: darkred">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                    {{ form.title }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date <span style="color: darkred">*</span></label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                                        {{ form.created_date }}
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                                        {{ form.created_time }}
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group "  style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                                <label for="cemail" class="control-label col-lg-3">Content </label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                    {{ form.content }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group "  style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                                <label for="cemail" class="control-label col-lg-3">Select Files </label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                    {{ form.files }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok and I can't see any problems with it. add a few print statements in your views to debug it. eg. print `files` to see actually how many  files views is getting. In the loop to create objects print something like `created` to check how many times the loop executed. Also after `obj = MyModel.objects.create()` you don't need to use `.save()`, unless you do something like `obj.field = 'changed'`, then `obj.save()`is required to update its field `field` to `"changed"`. save is required when initializing an object like this `obj = MyModel()`

Comment: Have a closer look at what update_matter_instance does if the request is not a POST.

Comment: Just redirected if method is not POST .. and it redirected fine.. More like method is not POST .. What could be wrong?    ` else:

        return redirect('matter_list')`
 @DanielRoseman

Comment: The point is that the last three lines of the function are indented one level too far.

Comment: @DanielRoseman..... Hahaha.. Its funny how i spent almost 12 Hours reviewing the code .. and i didnt see an indented issue .. Thanks alot for pointing to the right direction.